# How can we connect two meshes with python code?

Tags: python, 3d, 3d-reconstruction

I am new in 3D with programming. I don't know much about 3D stuffs. My question is how can we connect 3D head obj (Flame model) and 3D body obj (SMPL model) together using python code.

I know there is api called bpy from blender can do that part but I want to use other library assets without using bpy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.